# Jinja2 validate ip address

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, ipv4

I have a variable

> item["name"]

inside a jinja template that can be an ipv4 or ipv6 address.
I need to differentiate the 2 case. Is there any filter in jinja for IPv4 IPv6?No Ansible, no Salt is simply a python project.

I want to reach teh below

```
{% for item  in v['policy-options'] %}
        {% if item["name"] is_one_IPV4    %%}
            ip prefix-list {{item}}
        {% endif %}
        {% if item["name"]  is_one_IPV6  %%}
            ipv6 prefix-list {{item}}
        {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: no builtin filter jinja2. so  ipv6 contains `:`  and ipv4 contains `.`  or length op ipv6 is longer than ipv4

Comment: @Frenchy `::1` is not longer than `127.0.0.1`

Comment: yes....!!! forget the length

Comment: But, then, if this is a Python application, make that logic in your controller, in Python, and not in Jinja.